# date between two dates in two fields

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I am working in hotel domain. i was created the inventory page for each hotel along with each rooms.

In data structure of db i have created with start date and end date. while inventory we pass the record in between dates.

```
SELECT `crs_room_type_detail`.*, `crs_room_type`.`room_type_name`
FROM (`crs_room_type_detail`)
JOIN `crs_room_type` ON `crs_room_type_detail`.`room_type_id` = `crs_room_type`.`room_type_id`
WHERE `crs_room_type_detail`.`hotel_id` =  '4'
AND `crs_room_type_detail`.`sdate` >=  '2016-09-21'
AND `crs_room_type_detail`.`edate` <=  '2016-10-04'
GROUP BY `crs_room_type_detail`.`room_type_id`
```

This the query to get the result.
for Rooms we had the sdate : 2016-09-20 and edate : 2016-09-30 this criteria it wont work, suppose  i changes condition like `sdate` <=  '2016-09-21' and `edate` >=  '2016-10-04' its wont work some other criteria

Comment: for Rooms we had the sdate : 2016-09-20 and edate : 2016-09-30  .it won't work because query is  `sdate` >=  '2016-09-21'`  so `2016-09-20` missed

Comment: I want to be between two dates

Answer (score 1):

**Try out the following script:**

```
SELECT `crs_room_type_detail`.*, `crs_room_type`.`room_type_name`, date
FROM (`crs_room_type_detail`)
JOIN `crs_room_type` ON `crs_room_type_detail`.`room_type_id` =
`crs_room_type`.`room_type_id`
WHERE `crs_room_type_detail`.`hotel_id` =  '4'
AND date(`crs_room_type_detail`.`sdate`) >=  date('2016-09-21')
AND date(`crs_room_type_detail`.`edate`) <=  date('2016-10-04')
GROUP BY `crs_room_type_detail`.`room_type_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

use between to get date range:

```
SELECT `crs_room_type_detail`.*, `crs_room_type`.`room_type_name`
FROM (`crs_room_type_detail`)
JOIN `crs_room_type` ON `crs_room_type_detail`.`room_type_id` = `crs_room_type`.`room_type_id`
WHERE `crs_room_type_detail`.`hotel_id` =  '4'
AND `crs_room_type_detail`.`sdate` between  '2016-09-21' and '2016-10-04'
GROUP BY `crs_room_type_detail`.`room_type_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This One

```
 SELECT `crs_room_type_detail`.*, `crs_room_type`.`room_type_name`
    FROM (`crs_room_type_detail`)
    JOIN `crs_room_type` ON `crs_room_type_detail`.`room_type_id` = `crs_room_type`.`room_type_id`
    WHERE `crs_room_type_detail`.`hotel_id` =  '4'
    AND `crs_room_type_detail`.`sdate` BETWEEN '2016-09-21' AND '2016-10-04'
    AND `crs_room_type_detail`.`edate` BETWEEN '2016-09-21' AND '2016-10-04'
    GROUP BY `crs_room_type_detail`.`room_type_id`
```